# Join two vertical arrays in certain order into new vertical array using a function/formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, repeat, flatten

For Google Sheets Specifically. I have two vertical arrays of data that I want to combine into one array, that uses first a data point from the first array, then all of the data from the second array, then it uses the next data point from the first array, then all of the data from the second array again, kind of repeating, for length of Array 1. The length of Array 1 and Array 2 can change overtime as data gets input. Example:

| A `(Length Unknown)` | B `(Length Unknown)` | C `(Desired)` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | A |
| B | 2 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 2 |
| D | ... | 3 |
| ... |  | B |
| ... |  | 1 |
|  |  | 2 |
|  |  | 3 |
|  |  | C |
|  |  | 1 |
|  |  | 2 |
|  |  | 3 |
|  |  | D |
|  |  | 1 |
|  |  | 2 |
|  |  | 3 |

Been trying to use transpose, flatten, split, join, rept, CountA(A:A), and such, etc but not been having much luck. I feel like there should be some type of formula for this.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=lambda(z,filter(z,z<>""))(lambda(x,y,reduce(,sequence(counta(x)),lambda(a,c,{a;index(x,c);y})))(filter(A:A,A:A<>""),filter(B:B,B:B<>"")))
```

Incase [new functions](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/200022527?hl=en) have rolled out for you; this works too:

```
=tocol(reduce(,sequence(counta(tocol(A:A,1))),lambda(a,c,{a;index(tocol(A:A,1),c);tocol(B:B,1)})),1)
```

[image]